# using date type with vee-validate

Tags: vee-validate

I am working on a project in Nuxt which uses [Nuxt-Validate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-validate). According to the page it uses [Vee Validate](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/overview.html#installation), I tried using `input type='date'` with format of `dd/MM/yyyy` but it wasn't working and I found [this](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/1732) on google.

According to the github issue, it should be resolved in version 3 which is VeeValidate but Nuxt-Validate is on version 1.

Does it mean that Nuxt-Validate hasn't got the updated version where they fixed the issue? Is there any way I can use format other the default i.e `yyyy/MM/dd`